# Keep JQuery UI 1.9 Tooltip on screen

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I wonder how to insert controls (buttons, forms, etc) inside JQuery UI tooltips.

How to keep them visible and fade them out using a delay / mouseout control, with custom content ajax loaded?

url: /ajax/tooltip_content.html

```
<a href="a" id="mylink">mouse hover here</a>

$("#mylink").tooltip();
```